# How to change a label's color that is present in a repeater on its Onload function?

Tags: c#, asp.net

As the title says, I have a label inside repeater and I want to change its color according to its text value. Is there any way I can do that without mess?

```
<asp:Label ID="lblVerified" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("post_verified")%>' OnLoad="lblVerified_Load"
```

What I want to do is if Eval("post_verified").Equals(Yes) the color should be green and for "NO" it should be red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using a conditional operator :

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblVerified" ForeColor='<%# (Eval("post_verified").Equals("Yes")) ? "Green" : "Red" %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("post_verified")%>' OnLoad="lblVerified_Load">
```

Worked like a charm with this little edit :

```
<asp:Label ID="lblVerified" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("post_verified")%>' ForeColor='<%# (Eval("post_verified").Equals("yes")) ?  System.Drawing.Color.Green : System.Drawing.Color.Red %>'>
```

Comment: Hi I liked the answer but A little problem Occurred. Following Error Came: " Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Drawing.Color' "

Comment: Try this  
ForeColor='<%# (Eval("post_verified").Equals("Yes")) ? ConsoleColor.Green : ConsoleColor.Red %>'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "inside a repeater" you mean that the label is inside an `ItemTemplate` or an `AlternatingItemTemplate` then you should be using the `Repeater`'s `ItemDataBound` event instead of the label's `OnLoad` event because the `OnLoad` event happens too early.

You will need to declare the event handler...

```
repearter1.ItemDataBound += repearter1_ItemDataBound;
```

then in the event handler you can find and manipulate the label control...

```
 void repearter1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
 {
            Label lblVerified = e.Item.FindControl("lblVerified") as Label;

            if (lblVerified != null)
            {
                 //TODO: manipulate the control
            }
  }
```

Notice that you can also get data item from inside the `ItemDataBound` event if you do the following...

```
var dataItem = e.Item.DataItem as WhateverTheUnderlyingTypeIs;
```

Comment: That is really Cool I can use this thing for other stuff. thanks